# Recursively Tabulate All Folder Contents in Power Query

Tags: recursion, powerquery-m

## Background

As discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76709757) on Stack Overflow, I am comparing a local and a OneDrive version of the same superfolder, in order to identify discrepancies in the sync.  As such, I must compare *all* files and (sub)folders.

I am using Power Query to list the full contents of each superfolder.  Since comparison will require various [`Table.*Join()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-join)s, then I must combine all (sub)levels of contents into a single flat `table`: of the form yielded by [`Folder.Contents()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/folder-contents), but with far more data.

| Content | Name | Extension | Date accessed | Date Modified | Date created | Attributes | Folder Path |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| **Binary** | file.ext | .ext | *7/24/2023 4:21:00 PM* | *7/1/2023 1:00:00 PM* | *2/1/2023 9:00:00 AM* | **Record** | C:\Users\greg\OneDrive - My Company\Superfolder |
| **Table** | Folder |  | *7/24/2023 4:21:03 PM* | *6/30/2023 5:00:00 PM* | *1/1/2023 12:00:00 AM* | **Record** | C:\Users\greg\OneDrive - My Company\Superfolder |
| **Binary** | sub_file.ext | .ext | *7/24/2023 4:21:06 PM* | *7/1/2023 2:00:00 PM* | *2/1/2023 10:00:00 AM* | **Record** | C:\Users\greg\OneDrive - My Company\Superfolder\Folder |
| **Table** | Subfolder |  | *7/24/2023 4:21:09 PM* | *6/30/2023 6:00:00 PM* | *1/1/2023 1:00:00 AM* | **Record** | C:\Users\greg\OneDrive - My Company\Superfolder\Folder |
| **⋮** | ⋮ | ⋮ | *⋮* | *⋮* | *⋮* | **⋮** | ⋮ |

**Observe how the row for a folder contains a `table` object under the `[Content]` column, which describes the contents of *that* folder in identical fashion.**

## Solutions

With tens of thousands of files, and a deeply nested folder structure, I am seeking the most performant solution.  So far, I have developed two recursive approaches:

### Solution 1: Query Each Folder

```m
let Folder_FullContents = (
    // The only real input.
    path as text,
    
    // Mimics the signature of Folder.Contents().
    optional options as nullable record
) as table =>
    let
        // Buffer the first level of folder contents, specifically path scalars.
        contents = Table.Buffer(Folder.Contents(path, options)),
        
        // List the full paths to each subfolder.
        subfolders = Table.AddColumn(
            Table.SelectRows(contents, each [Attributes][Directory]),
            "File Path",
            each Text.Combine({[Folder Path], [Name]}),
            type text
        )[File Path],
        
        // Prepend the current contents to those returned from the subfolders.
        result = Table.Combine(List.Combine({
            {contents},
            List.Transform(subfolders, @Folder_FullContents)
        }))
    in result
in Folder_FullContents
```

### Solution 2: Unnest Root Contents

The engine of this solution is **`Folder_UnnestContents()`**, which flattens and consolidates the `table`s nested in the `[Content]` column yielded by `Folder.Contents()`.

```m
let Folder_UnnestContents = (table as table) as table =>
    let
        // Buffer the table, as recommended on Stack Overflow.
        tbl = Table.Buffer(table),
        
        // Prepend the current contents to [Content] extracted from the subfolders.
        result = Table.Combine(List.Combine({
            {tbl},
            List.Transform(
                Table.SelectRows(tbl, each [Attributes][Directory])[Content],
                @Folder_UnnestContents
            )
        }))
    in result
in Folder_UnnestContents
```

Then it is simple to implement **`Folder_FullContents()`**:

```m
let Folder_FullContents = (
    path as text,
    optional options as nullable record
) as table =>
    let
        // Buffer the contents, as recommended on Stack Overflow.
        contents = Table.Buffer(Folder.Contents(path, options)),
        
        // Unnest those contents via the engine.
        result = Folder_UnnestContents(contents)
    in result
in Folder_FullContents
```

## Questions

1. **How should [`.Buffer()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powerquery-m/table-buffer)ing really be handled here?**  I was [advised](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76710216) on Stack Overflow to buffer liberally, but upon [further discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76709757#comment135250660_76710216), it seems the benefits might not extend to the `[Content]` column, with its objective (not scalar) data.
2. **Which of these approaches is more performant at scale**, especially on deeply nested (sub)folders?  My VPN connections are volatile, so I cannot establish a consistent baseline to gauge performance.
3. **Which of them is more stable**, especially against modifications made to the file structure *while the query is loading*?

   I suspect that **Solution 2** might prove more robust against modifications to file structure in real time, particularly when the query takes a long time to run.  Its single call to `Folder.Contents()` presumably (?) captures one coherent "snapshot" of the structure; but **Solution 1** runs `Folder.Contents()` on each subfolder, with small window of delay between each.  Or does the latter occur anyway, even with **Solution 2**, whenever a `table` object is accessed under the `[Content]` column?